# JavaScript getting error on valid code

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, error-handling

I am getting an error with this JavaScript code that loads a JSON file:

```
function loadJSON(){
    var xmlhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest){
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){
            j = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
                    //I get the "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }" error on the line above
            jsonLoaded = 1;
            init();
        };
    };
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "things.json", true);
    xmlhttp.send();
};
```

**Why am I getting this error?** This same script was working a few hours ago.

Thanks!

Comment: Try printing `xmlhttp.responseText` fore you try to `JSON.parse()` it. I doubt it's what you expect anymore.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart Ok, I'll try it.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart It may just be invalid JSON because it _is_ loading the file.